# Apple Match-O-Linker (Id) Error using CorePlot Framework

Tags: macos, core-plot, linker-errors

I'm migrating a project developed in Xcode6 for MacOSX from another MacBook where it was running just fine.

Here when I run my project I get all these errors:

[image]

as you can see the framework is correctly added
Now then I look for the error description and I found this:

[image]

all those errors are from methods used from CorePlot Framework

[image]

but the coreplot framework is already added on my project, what else do I need for make this work???

thanks for the supportmac

Comment: Have you done a clean build of the whole project, including the Core Plot framework?

Comment: Yes like a zillion times but I get the same result

Comment: Looks to me as if coreplot is simply not linked at all. Look earlier in the build process if you see a message like "ignoring ... because of differences in architecture" or similar (don't remember the exact wording). You may have an arch conflict here (XCode adjusted your project settings, right?).

Comment: I could fix it by adding physically all the CorePlotHeaders to my project, thanks for the support

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that with a framework. Try deleting the "Derived Data" folder (Preferences -> Locations). If that doesn't fix it, remove the Core Plot framework from the app project and add it back.